# Using 'show' with 'treatment'

Tags: word-choice, verbs, nouns, collocation, speech

Is it proper to say 'show special treatment' for example in "He showed him special treatment."?

I know it sounds more natural to say, "He took a special interest in him because of his background." but is it weird to say "He showed him special interest and treatment because of his background."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More natural will be:
He *showed* special interest in him.
He *gave* him special treatment.
Examples of interest/attention and treatment used in the same sentence:

1. He took a special interest in him and gave him a good treatment because of his background.
2. He gave him a good treatment because he took special interest in him due to his background.
3. He showed special interest in him for his (due to) his background and gave him special treatment.
4. Because of his background, he showed special interest in him and gave him as speical treatment.
5. He showed special interest in him and treated him special because of his background.
6. He showed special interest in him by giving him special treatment.
7. He showed special interest in him due to his background and hence gave him special treatment.
8. He showed special interest in him for his background and gave him special treatment.

Comment: Oh, so even 'take a special interest in" is unnatural? And, how would you use both 'interest/attention' and 'treatment' in the same sentence.

Comment: added more examples. Take a special interest in is not unnatural, just not fitting it right in this situation.

Comment: oh wow, thanks for the examples. So, to put it simply, a 'show' + 'treatment' construction is wierd.

Comment: added few more examples.